# How do I identify a message using JMS Correlation ID?

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

How do I identify a message using JMS Correlation ID? I'm using code like the following, but I can't get the message out of the queue. The tool has confirmed that there is a message in the queue with `JMSCorrelationID ='ID: 1234567'` set in PropertiesText. What's wrong? Is it possible to include spaces in the value specified for `JMSCorrelationID`?
Is it possible to use a value like `'ID: 1234 ABC'`?

Sender:

```java
    MessageProducer mproducer;
    Session qSession;
    ...
    String selectKey = "'' ID: 1234567'";
    ObjectMessage msg = qSession.createObjectMessage (data);
    msg.setJMSCorrelationID (selectKey);
    mProducer.send (msg);
```

Receiver

```java
    Session qSession;
    ...
    String selectMsgKey = "JMSCorrelationID ='ID: 1234567'";
    MessageConsumer mConsumer.createConsumer (queue, selectMsgKey);
    mConsumer.receive (60000);
```

I use ActiveMQ Artemis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have spaces in a correlation ID. I believe the problem is the way you're defining `selectKey` in your sender. You have extra `'` characters in there. You should simply use:

```java
String selectKey = "ID: 1234567";
```

Then your selector should work.

Comment: Thank you,Justin. I can now get the message normally by the method you taught me.